# Emberjs: Using Slugs With Pod Structure

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, slug

I'm having difficulty using slugs with the pod structure. Specifically when I try to go to a listing page directly, it does not work. Slug is a computed property in the model.

ember -v:
version: 1.13.1,
node: 0.12.7,
npm: 2.12.1,

app/listings/show/route.js

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    console.log('MODEL params.pageslug', params.page_slug);
    var listings = this.modelFor('listings');
    return listings.findBy('slug', params.page_slug);
  },
  serialize(model, params) {
    console.log('SERIALIZE model slug', model.get('slug'));
    return { page_slug: model.get('slug') };
  }
});
```

app/router.js

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('listings', function() {
        this.route('show', { path: ':page_slug' });
    });
});
```

When I go to /listings/slug directly, I see neither of the console logs. Ember gives `Preparing to transition from '' to ' not-found'` `Transitioned into 'not-found'` (not-found is our 404 route)

When I go to /listings/listing_id directly (ie: /listings/1), I see my MODEL log with params.page_slug as '1', and the correct page is loaded without any model attributes. Ember gives `Preparing to transition from '' to ' listings.show'` `Transitioned into 'listings.show'`

If I were to go to /listings then click on a listing, my SERIALIZE log displays with the correct slug value, but no model log. So it seems to be skipping my model() function (I assume because the model is already given from /listings)

I feel like I'm misunderstanding something simple here.

Comment: Doing more work, the findBy() in the model function is returning undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what was happening, was ember was sending a request with query slug parameter to my rails backend. But the rails method receiving the call didn't handle the situation when parameters were sent to it. So I needed this in the my rails controller:

```
def index
    if params[:slug]
        @listing = Listing.find_by_slug(params[:slug])
    else
        ...other stuff
    end
end
```